# configurable auto commit in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a inbuilt functionality in oracle for auto commit?
Like if i want to update a million rows ,and i want set auto commit to 1000 rows or 2000 rows,i have to just configure if somewhere.
It will update the million rows in a loop with autocommit after each 1000 or 2000 rows.This functionality is available in sqlloader.I want to know if similar functionality is available in oracle too.

Comment: Read @justin's answer. Committing inside a loop is rarely needed, and will slow down your update and cause many more problems than you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  You cannot ask Oracle to incrementally commit the work that a single SQL statement is doing.  That would violate the Atomicity part of ACID compliance so it would be a really bad thing for a relational database to allow.  Doing so would mean that if the database failed or if the statement failed after processing N rows, you'd have no way of knowing which N rows had been processed.  Doing so would mean that other users could see partially complete data causing their reports to be incorrect and their queries to potentially return misleading results.

You can, of course, write your own custom logic that updates rows in batches.  That is generally, however, a bad idea.  It will take longer, potentially much longer, to run a process that is doing interim commits.  It will require writing code to make sure that the procedure is re-entrant (that is, that it can pick up where it left off in the event of a server failure without trying to re-update rows that were already updated and committed or at least not update the data to a different value.  It will cause the update to generate more `UNDO` and `REDO` on the server.  It will require every process that uses the data to be aware that they could be reading it in the middle of processing an `UPDATE` statement.  And it increases the risk of an ORA-01555 error.  There is generally no need to have interim commits-- the downsides are very, very seldom worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can do this with [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23448/d_parallel_ex.htm).

The package is obviously meant for executing things in parallel, but it also commits after each "chunk".  You can set the `chunk_size` to 1000 or 2000 rows, and set the `parallel_level` to 0 to run in serial.

Here is a simple example:

```
create table table1(a number);
insert into table1 select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;

begin
    dbms_parallel_execute.create_task('update_table1');

    dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_rowid(
        task_name => 'update_table1',
        table_owner => user,
        table_name => 'TABLE1',
        by_row => true,
        chunk_size => 1000
    );

    dbms_parallel_execute.run_task(
        task_name => 'update_table1',
        sql_stmt => 'update table1 set a = 5 where rowid between :start_id and :end_id',
        language_flag => dbms_sql.native,
        parallel_level => 0);
end;
/
```

Try killing the query or session half-way through.  You can see only some of the changes were commited, and you can track the chunk status with `dba_parallel_execute_chunks`.

---

**HOWEVER**, I agree with Justin Cave and Wolf that this functionality is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: i will try this and let you know...this looks promising

Comment: is this feature only availble for 11g...becoz on production machine ,we have oracle 10g only :(

Comment: is there a alternative for 10g as well?

Comment: @subodh1989 Yes, this is a new 11g feature.  I do not know of any alternative for 10g.

Answer (score -3):

Syntax
AUTOCOMMIT { ON | OFF }
Description
Turns the connection's auto-commit mode on or off. JDBC specifies that the default auto-commit mode is ON. Certain types of processing require that auto-commit mode be OFF. For information about auto-commit, see the Java DB Developer's Guide.

If auto-commit mode is changed from off to on when there is a transaction outstanding, that work is committed when the current transaction commits, not at the time auto-commit is turned on. Use Commit or Rollback before turning on auto-commit when there is a transaction outstanding, so that all prior work is completed before the return to auto-commit mode.

```
Example
ij> autocommit off;
ij> DROP TABLE menu;
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted 
ij> CREATE TABLE menu (course CHAR(10), item CHAR(20), price INT);
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> INSERT INTO menu VALUES ('entree', 'lamb chop', 14),
('dessert', 'creme brulee', 6), 
('appetizer', 'baby greens', 7); 
3 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> commit;
ij> autocommit on;
ij>
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Additionally: `ij` is not the Oracle commandline SQL tool and the syntax for the INSERT statement is also wrong for Oracle.